# Syntax error at inserting a serialized string

Tags: mysql, serialization

after an update of my Linux webserver and an updated version of the SQL Server, some of my default used INSERT statements won't work anymore.

The VM is running on Ubuntu 16.04 with SQL 5.7.15 and phpMyAdmin 4.6.2

Now i tried to fix this and have currently the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id ,element_id ,shop_id ,value) 
VALUES 
(NULL ,  235,  1,  s:4:"smtp";) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = s:4:"smtp";;
```

SQL gives me a syntax error:

```
...to use near ':4:"smtp"'
```

Does anyone have an idea, how i can fix this and insert the serialized string?

Comment: This should be wrapped in quotes `(NULL ,  235,  1,  's:4:"smtp";') `

Comment: is that double  semicolon(s:4:"smtp";;) after "smpt" causes the issue? you need to use quotes carefully here.

Comment: @e4c5 Are you certain that the serialized string is not something which is coming from the Linux environment?

Comment: serialized string is used only on the website. I tried the statement with the quotes also, but it gives me the same error.